# Using a Fragment inside my ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

If I want to reuse a Fragment inside my ArrayAdapter, is that inefficient?

That is, in my `ArrayAdapter`, my `getView()` would look like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment();
        return userFragment.getView();
}
```

I ask, because normally in the `getView()` method, it looks something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);
            ...//do stuff
        }
```

Is it inefficient to create a Fragment each time the getView() is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Fragment` has its own life cycle, like `Activity`'s `onCreate`, `onDestory`, etc.
So if you do `UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment()` in `getView()`, every time you scroll the `ListView`, a lot of different `Fragment`'s instances will be created and scroll-out ones will be GC. This costs a lot.

Second, you are not reusing views. Each `Fragment`'s instance has its own view structure, so `userFragment.getView()` will return a brand new `View` each time.

Basically, it is not recommended to use `Fragment` inside `ListView`. Use `convertView` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A `Fragment` is managed by a `FragmentManager` (through `FragmentTransactions`) owned by an `Activity`. Or you can have Fragments in Fragments.

A `ListView` manages its own views separately and also is recycling these views so when you scroll you'll get in `convertView` the view that you should use.

Bottom-line is: fragments reside ONLY in activities or in other fragments, while Views (`ListView` is a descendant of `View`) stay in Fragments or in Activities.

So: `Is it inefficient to create a Fragment each time the getView() is called?`. I see no reason why you should do this. In fact, it would be 1000 times more helpful to make [push-ups](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh00_rniF8E) instead of using Fragments in Views. There is not a single good technical article where somebody discusses these.